# Restriction from Firebase RT Database doesnt work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have set this access-restrictions to my Firebase Database:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

So by my understanding, I shouldn't be able to read or write to or from the database, without an authentication. But in my app I can access write values using following code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("user");
myRef.child("id").setValue("0000");
```

And the value will be set, without providing any form of authentication.

Did somebody else have this problem or knows the solution to this one?

Thanks

Comment: If the write is allowed after you save those rules, there *is* an authenticated user. To verify that, log `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` right before writing to the database.

Comment: You're right! Is there a way to delete the current user (reset it)?

Comment: `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the write is allowed after you save those rules, there is an authenticated user. To verify that, log `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` right before writing to the database.

To sign out the user, use `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`.